# Search Bar crashing app when inputting characters

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UITableView` that is populating locations and a Search Bar set as the header of that `UITableView`.

Whenever certain characters are entered, or a certain amount of characters are entered, the app crashes, giving me no error code.

Sometimes the app crashes after inputting one character, maybe 2 characters, maybe 3, or maybe 4. There seems to be no apparent reason behind the crashing.

The search function properly searches and populates the filtered results, but for no apparent reason, crashes if a seemingly arbitrary amount of characters are inputted.

I have tried using the exception breakpoint tool already, and it is providing me with no new information. I think it has something to do with if there are no search results.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Locations..."
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        locationTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        filteredData = locationList

        // Sets this view controller as presenting view controller for the search interface
        definesPresentationContext = true

        locationList = createArray()

        // Reload the table
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.locationTableView.numberOfSections)
        let sections = NSIndexSet(indexesIn: range)
        self.locationTableView.reloadSections(sections as IndexSet, with: .fade)
    }

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}

func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
    filteredData = locationList.filter({( locationName : Location) -> Bool in
        return locationName.locationName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    })

    let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.locationTableView.numberOfSections)
    let sections = NSIndexSet(indexesIn: range)
    self.locationTableView.reloadSections(sections as IndexSet, with: .fade)

}

func isFiltering() -> Bool {
    return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
}

func locationTableView(_ locationTableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    return locationList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let locationCell = locationTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locationCell", for: indexPath) as! locationCell
    let location: Location
    if isFiltering() {
        location = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        location = locationList[indexPath.row]
    }

    locationCell.setLocation(location: location)


    return locationCell
}
```

The expected result is that the `UITableView` should populate with filtered results. Instead, it populates them and crashes if too many characters are inputted (usually 1-4 characters).

---

EDIT 1: I have found through debugging the error:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

appears on Line 2 on this block of code:

```
if isFiltering() {
        location = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        location = locationList[indexPath.row]
    }
```

---

EDIT 2: This is the tutorial I used.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should look into using `guard` statements instead of non-else conditionals.

Comment: how would I implement `guard` statements in this scenario?

Comment: Hey @KSDKhan! If you replace `locationTableView.reloadSections` with `locationTableView.reloadData()` temporary just to check if it is the case. I suspect the `filteredData.count` changes but the table view doesn't know about that and. If this helps you can also look into using batch update instead of reloading the sections.

Comment: @Denis I am currently using the reload sections for the purposes of animating the disappearing and appearing of tableview cells, I have changed it to reload data for the time being. How would I go about batch updating the sections in this scenario? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can explain more as soon as we know that `reloadData` helps to fix the crash. If it doesn't then probably the issue in a different place

Comment: `reloadData` still causes crashes, which stinks because I would have lived without the animations if it just didn't crash @Denis

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are expecting the tableView to provide YOU with the number of sections... it is supposed to be driven by your own datasource.

Since you are not providing a `numberOfSections` in your data source I'm assuming it is 1.  If all of your rows are in 1 section, all of the nifty reloading you are doing could be greatly simplified.

I suggest you read up on UITableView dataSource protocol at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

---

Reviewing the tutorial you are reading, it seems it is using a `reloadData()` which forces the tableView to ignore previous number of rows and reload its content with a new number of rows.  And based on your findings so far, I would assume that is part of the root cause, with the tableview wrongly assuming a pre-determined number of rows and attempting to retrieve cells that are no longer within range.

Comment: I have switched the animation reloading part to just reload the tableview. If the second part is true, as it likely is, what would I do to rectify the problem?